# Проблема с дешифровкой на PHP

Tags: php, безопасность, шифрование

Привет, друзья! Сейчас осваиваю азы шифрования данных на php без стандартных функций. Помогите разобраться.

Есть таблица. Когда пользователь вводит текст и нажимает "Зашифровать", каждая введенная буква заменяется на две другие буквы, которые обозначены серым цветом.
[image: шифрование двойной заменой]
С шифрование проблем нет, а вот с дешифровкой не могу разобраться. Перепробовал несколько способов и постоянно выдает результат с ошибками. Некоторые буквы правильно дешифрует, а некоторые нет.

Вот мой код. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
<div class="container">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <form role="form" class="form form_control form-inline" method="POST">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="stroka" placeholder="Введите свой текст сюда">
        <input class="btn btn-success form-control" type="submit" value="Зашифровать" name="zashifr">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Расшифровать" name="rash">
    </form>
    <?      
    $str=' ';
    $flag=0;
    /*эти три масива таблицы*/
    $mas1=array("K", "A", "L", "G", "O", "N", "E");
    $mas2=array("D", "Y", "R", "S");
    $mas3=array(
        array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"),
        array("h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"),
        array("o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u"),
        array("v", "w", "x", "y", "z", ",", "."),
        );
    //объявление масиво завершено
    $str=$_POST['stroka'];
    if(isset($_POST['zashifr']))
    {
        if($str=='')
            echo "Нечего зашифровывать. Строка пустая";
        else
        {//шифруем текст, если введен текст
            for ($t=0; $t < strlen($str); $t++) 
            { 
                for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) 
                { 
                    for ($j=0; $j < 7; $j++) 
                    { 
                        if($mas3[$i][$j]==$str[$t])
                        {
                            $no_i=$i;
                            $no_j=$j;
                            echo $mas2[$no_i];
                            echo $mas1[$no_j];
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
            //шифровка завершена
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['rash']))
    {
        if($str=='')
            echo "Нечего РАСшифровывать. Строка пустая";
        else
        {//дешифруем текст, если введен текст
            echo $str;
            echo "<br>";
            for ($t=0; $t < strlen($str); $t++) 
            { 
                for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) 
                { 
                    if($mas2[$i]==$str[$t])
                        $bukva_1=$i;
                }
                for ($j=0; $j < 7; $j++) 
                { 
                    if($mas1[$j]==$str[$t])
                        $bukva_2=$j;
                }
                echo $mas3[$bukva_1][$bukva_2];
            }
            //дешифровка завершена
        }
    }
    ?>
    <p>Исходная таблица:</p>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed center">
        <thead>
            <?
            echo "<tr><td style='background:#e4e4e4;'><center>/</center></td>";
            for ($i=0; $i < 7; $i++) 
            { 
                echo "<td style='background:#e4e4e4;'><center>";
                echo $mas1[$i];
                echo "</center></td>";
            }
            ?>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            <?
            for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) 
            { 
                echo "<tr>";
                for ($j=0; $j < 8; $j++) 
                { 
                    echo "<td style='background:#e4e4e4;'><center>";
                    echo $mas2[$i];
                    echo "</center></td>";
                    for ($j=0; $j < 7; $j++) 
                    { 
                        echo "<td><center>";
                        echo $mas3[$i][$j];
                        echo "</center></td>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>      
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   {//дешифруем текст, если введен текст
        echo $str;
        echo "<br>";
        for ($t=0; $t < strlen($str); $t++) 
        { 
            for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) 
            { 
                if($mas2[$i]==$str[$t])
                    $bukva_1=$i;
            }
            $t++; // отето надо
            for ($j=0; $j < 7; $j++) 
            { 
                if($mas1[$j]==$str[$t])
                    $bukva_2=$j;
            }
            echo $mas3[$bukva_1][$bukva_2];
        }
        //дешифровка завершена
```